# Asp.Net MVC 3 ListBox will not select initial values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to set the initial values for a list box using asp.net mvc 3.  It does fill in the options, but doesn't select them.

Here is my code.  This attempt uses a hardcoded set of values

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(Function(model) model.PageTags, New MultiSelectList(Model.PageTags, "ID", "TagEn", New Integer(){1,2})
```

I have also tried an example that I would expect would select all the values.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(Function(model) model.PageTags, New MultiSelectList(Model.PageTags, "ID", "TagEn", Model.PageTags)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the selected values as an enumerable of "values" (and not an enumerable of the original "items"). In your case this should be a list of IDs. E.g. to select all try to pass the selected values like this: Model.PageTags.Select(i => i.ID)